# How to optimize webjob triggering from service bus queue to not use high cpu

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, webjob

I have webjob in azure which gets triggered from service bus queues. It has batch size of 100 and utilizes high cpu approx 90%. Need help how to make it 50%

I added cache and implemented lock so that all thread dont hit db and once one thread gets data from db and fills cache other threads get data from cache and apply where filters and return

Still no improvement

Comment: moving from db to cache won't change CPU consumption as it's stored in memory

Comment: What should i do to optimize cpu or reduce cpu usage? Shall i move cache or in memory where linq operations in db? Hitting 1 million times into db seems expensive for all queue items hence i moved data in cache. Threads are performing and maybe increasing cpu. How to reduce cpu?

Comment: I don't even know what you're trying to do. Can't provide any guidance. Add some code and maybe we can try to help.

Comment: I have a webjob which triggers from queue. It has batch size of 100. Hence it opens 100 threads in one go. Now, every thread tries to get data from DB then i implemented a lock and under lock i get data from DB and set the cache and return . Now, when other thread goes in lock then they will find data in cache hence db is saved for rest thread and then from cache they will get data and then after getting data I apply some filter condition using Where clauses using linq and then i perform some manipulation and then work gets completed. Same process happens for all threads.

Comment: After implementing cache so that all thread wont hit database, still no improvement in optimization.

Comment: again, changing db to cache won't change cpu, only latency